# update view after variable changes

Tags: angular, typescript, view, angular2-changedetection

I am using a library lib-sqv to display some html. If the field options has a value from the beginning, than the view displays the html correctly. Here is my working code if you want to try:

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
   ...
    SqvLibModule
]

bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**appComponent.html**

```
<div>
  <app-sqv></app-sqv>
</div>
```

**seqComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sqv',
  templateUrl: './seq.component.html'
})

export class SeqComponent {

  options;
}
```

**seqComponent.html**

```
<lib-sqv [op]="options"></lib-sqv>
```

EDIT:
This is the object I use:

```
options = {

  mode: 'viewSequence',

  parameters: {
  fontSize: '14px',
  chunkSize: 5,
  colorChoice: 'custom'
},

view: [
  'AATQADLMEGMATQADLMEJGMATQADLMEGMATQADLMMATQADLMEGMATQADLMEJGMATQADLMEGZZZZZZ'

],

colors: [
  {
    type: 'region',
    start: 1,
    end: 2,
    color: {r: 204, g: 255, b: 0, a: 0.4}
  }
]
```

};

I've tried to change the options value after clicking on a button, and it will actually change it... but the view will not update. 
How can I update it?

Comment: is `lib-sqv` your custom component ?

Comment: lib-sqv is an external library. It receives the options as @Input to generate some html.

Comment: what data type are `opt` argument and `options` parameter

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan they are an object.

Comment: Would be best if you could provide us the `options` to replicate this issue. The documentation is useless https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqv-lib their `options` object does not even work just to setup a basic demo.

Comment: We are going to need more details to be able to help you. Where does opt come from? How is it created?

Comment: @penleychan sorry, I should have explained before how to fill the options. I have updated my question now so it is simple to use the library. (You can install it with npm -i sqv-lib)

Comment: @shadowfox476 I have edited the post, so now there is a working example that should be clearer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<lib-sqv *ngIf="options" [op]="options"></lib-sqv>`

Or this

```
<div *ngIf="options">
    <lib-sqv [op]="options"></lib-sqv>
</div>
```

Since I'm not able to debug I can only guess that maybe something is breaking on load, this should load your element when options are populated

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it render anything on the HTML, however this should work.

First you need to get a reference of that component you can do that with:

`@ViewChild(SqvLibComponent, {static: false}) sqvLibComp !: SqvLibComponent;`

Then on your `public drawSqv(opt)` you just call the `draw` method.

`this.sqvLibComp.draw(opt);`

Here's the stackblitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxbfs5), as you can see on the console, it is triggering redraw.

Hint on how to do this was at the bottom of the npm readme:

> If needed, one can change the options input and changes will be displayed. To do so, import {SqvLibComponent} from ‘sqv-lib’ in your component, declare sqv: SqvLibComponent and instantiate this.sqv = new SqvLibComponent when needed. Lastly execute the method this.sqv.draw(this.options), which will draw the new Sequence Viewer with the new options.

Hope that helps.